# C# asp.net check if textbox contains spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to prevent the user from leaving the textbox empty and it worked with me using this code:

```
textbox1.Text != ""
```

but now I want to prevent entering spaces, I tried this code below but it doesn't prevent it:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox1.Text))
```

is there any other way to prevent entering spaces?

Comment: Use trim method

Comment: Can you handle the text changed event and cancel when its space? And or loop through the string looking for the space?

Comment: @David  if is spaces with letters no problem but if it is only spaces I want to prevent it

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What do you mean by "prevent"? Do you want a masked textbox, that does not allow any space characters to be entered, using JavaScript or using HTML5's `pattern`  attribute? Then what about serverside validation, which you need anyway because anyone can post anything they want if they modify your HTML and JS? How do you want to "prevent" this, what do you want to happen if you encounter invalid input? Do you use MVC (ModelState validation), or WebForms? Is `" "` invalid, but `"A "` valid? what about `"A B"`?

Comment: you can try this  
bool b= textBox1.Text.Length>0 && textBox1.Text.Trim().Length==0;

Comment: Add validations on your control as well i.e. required

Comment: @CodeCaster I mean if the user enter only spaces using space button and then click submit a warnning message should show that says invalid data

Comment: @arater2000: `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox1.Text)` would indeed catch if a string contains *only* whitespace characters.  How have you determined otherwise?  Can you provide an example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @David when I use the code like this: if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox1.Text)){ //do something else{//do nothing} but it do something

Comment: @arater2000: That line of code doesn't compile.  Nor does it demonstrate the problem.  It sounds like you have an invalid assumption somewhere in your debugging.  You are currently asserting that whatever other code you have *must* be correct and that there *must* be a bug in the `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method.  If you're *absolutely certain* that you've found a bug in the .NET Framework, then the next step would be to report it to Microsoft.  But it is *extremely unlikely* that this is the case.  If you can provide a complete example which demonstrates the problem, we can help you spot it.

Comment: @David  you are correct I had an error in another page and I disables the error warnning message,,,,,,,,,,,, my bad :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to check if the value *contains* a space character?  The string object has a method to check that:

```
if (!textBox1.Text.Contains(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following simply removes the spaces:

```cs
textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text.Replace(" " ,"");
```

Comment: I need the code in if condition so that when thee user click submit a warnning message will show

Comment: I would suggest to use a mask on the front-end side of things to prevent users from entering it, but you should also use the above to prevent clients to submit the fields while skipping your javascript checks.

Answer (score 0):

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text.Trim()))

//then what you want to do

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).